# Network bandwith and packet size relationship over ethernet network

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming, ethernet

Suppose I have 2 Mbps line is equal to 2,000,000 bits per second.
Which is equal to 250,000 bytes per second. Which is equal to 250 bytes per millisecond. That means we can only send/receive message of size 250 bytes per millisecond. What will happened if send/receive more than 1 packet of 250 bytes per milisecond.

Comment: Well normally - most of the Ethernet cards, switches, routers  have buffers. So the packets that you cannot send immediately are buffered. But buffers are finite resources, eventually they will start getting filled and then the packets are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

If a sender attempts to send data at a higher rate than the network can support, initially the data will be buffered - in the network card, operating systems buffers, and/or buffers in the sending process.  Eventually the buffers will fill, and the sending thread or process will be blocked until buffers are emptied.

If buffers on routers or the receiving system are filled, packets are dropped.

Maximum Ethernet packet sizes have been about 1500 bytes until Gigabit Ethernet came along.  With higher speeds, *jumbo frames* were implemented which increased packet sizes to about 9k bytes.

Comment: Well, every link transmits only either 0 or 1 at any specific moment. So if your router connected to 2Mbit/s link receives first 250 bytes packet, and assuming that it doesn't have anything at the moment to send, it will pass the 250 bytes into the interface driver, and then serialize it (meaning put 0s and 1s) onto a link.

The next packet, even if it's just milisecond later, will wait for the first packet to be transmitted. This may incur delay in sending (alone) of 1 milisecond, but that's just theory - in reality, there will be some additional, minimal delay depending on the device.